# How do I find the $\sup\{s_{n+1}-s_n|n\geq 1\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{s_n\}$ be a sequence in $[0,1]$. Assume that $2s_n\leq s_{n-1}+s_{n+1}, n\geq 1.$ Then

1. $\lim_{n\to \infty}s_{n+1}-s_n=\text{doesn't exist}$
2. $\lim_{n\to \infty}s_{n+1}-s_n=0$
3. $\lim_{n\to \infty}s_{n+1}-s_n=\frac{1}{2}$
4. $\lim_{n\to \infty}s_{n+1}-s_n=1$

**My attempt:-**

$$2s_n\leq s_{n-1}+s_{n+1}$$
$$\implies s_n-s_{n-1}\leq s_{n+1}-s_n$$
$$\implies (s_2-s_1)  \leq...(s_{n-1}-s_{n-2})\leq (s_n- s_{n-1}) \leq ( s_{n+1}-s_{n}) $$

Hence the sequence $\{s_{n+1}-s_n \}$ increasing and bounded above. Hence $\lim_{n\to \infty}s_{n+1}-s_n=\sup\{s_{n+1}-s_n|n\geq 1\}$

So, option(1) is wrong.

How do I find the supremum of $\sup\{s_{n+1}-s_n|n\geq 1\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2. is true. Here is a hint; If $l=\lim (s_{n+1}-s_n) >0$ then $s_{n+1} >s_n+\frac l 2$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Iterate this to get the contradiction that $s_n >1$ for $n$ large enough. Similarly, $l <0$ would give $s_n <0$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: can you please elaborate on how did you arrive at the contradiction that $s_n > 1$ ?